# What were Hitler's religious beliefs?

Tags: 20th-century, religion, hitler

Hitler is often cited as an example of an evil atheist (along with Stalin and Mao). But there are several quotes from him that seem to indicate he believed in the Christian God - and even used this to justify his policies.

So what were Hitler's actual religious beliefs, as far as History is concerned? Is there any evidence that supports the claim that he was an atheist?

Comment: I think they're quite confusing, to say the least. He was raised non-strictly as Christian (Catholic even?) but seemed to lean towards neo-Germanic paganism at some times. At other time, he refuted paganism and reasserted Christian beliefs.

Comment: I would not be surprised if it turned out that Hitler had Buddhist leanings (I'm favorable to Buddhism, but not to Hitler: this is just a conclusion from some evidence surrounding other Nazi figures.)

Comment: @Noldorin: Hitler was raised Lutheran. Religion was important to him. He did gain the approval of the Catholic pope (the first when he came to power opposed him, but that pope died and was replaced by one which approved - which I supposed the religious see as one of 'His mysterious ways')

Comment: @otakucode: Ah right, I didn't know he was Lutheran. I believe they're quite a minority in Austria (and were at the time indeed), since the vast majority are Roman Catholic. The situation with Pius XI & XII is interested. Both certainly opposed Nazi ideology, and Pius XII although he sought safety for the Catholic church in Germany (why wouldn't he from a political perspective?), became very critical of Hitler & the Naxis when WWII broke out, as far as I know.

Comment: @otakucode Hitler NEVER was a luteran.

Comment: @Anixx, what is the evidence that he was never a Lutheran? although according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_views_of_Adolf_Hitler he was raised by a Catholic mother so maybe that is where he got his religious influence from

Comment: @Drux Buddhist? Where on earth did you get that idea from? I can't think of anyone who represented more the antithesis of Buddhism!

Comment: @WS2 Think of [Heinrich Harrer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Harrer) who allowed his (otherwise great first ascent through the Eiger North Face) to be used for propaganda. He received more compassion in Tibet that might have been available to him in post-war Europe.

Comment: @WS2 Or think of [Richard Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Wagner). While on the level of art he is a great composer, on the level of personality there remains little double which side we would have supported as a contemporary of the Nazis. If I'm not mistaken, he planned his final Opera to deal with the Buddha's life.

Comment: Hitler has said that Islam was the only religion he was willing to respect: "The only religion I respect is Islam. The only prophet I admire is the Prophet Muhammad." - He despised the perceived weakness of Christianity and was inspired by the aggressiveness of Islam. At the end, this basic sentiment is also the reason why the Nazi attitude towards the Jews was virtually identical to the current jihadist attitude.

Comment: @LubošMotl do you have a source for that quote?

Comment: Dear iain, it appears in Kevin Coogan, "The Mysterious Achmed Huber: Friend of Hitler, Allah...and Bin Laden?" where you might get more details.

Comment: *Hitler is often cited as an example of an evil atheist* Is he ? I'd like a source for such a citation.

Comment: Do you mean the beliefs he professed or the beliefs he practiced?

Comment: *But there are several quotes from him that...* -> adding one or two such quotes (with sources) in the body of the question would be helpful.

Comment: In a way, National-Socialism and Communism are religions themselves, or at least attempts at substituting their system of beliefs to existing religion(s). In this sense *atheism* is probably not the right word.

Answer (score 35):

That's an interesting question. There is a book by Michael Hesemann, a German historian, in which he is interpreting Hitler's religion (that is actually the title of the book) like this:

Hitler's plans were going towards a "German pseudo-religion". Hitler got his first ideas from the "Ostara"-magazine, which was published from 1903 to 1931 and propagated Aryan and antisemitic theories.

The publisher, an Austrian named Jörg Lanz von Liebenfels, wanted to get his followers to convert to Protestantism, but most of the Austrian population was strictly Catholic at this time, so he failed.

So Hitler, not wanting to share the fate of Liebenfels, had to keep a Catholic facade. He needed the church (Catholic and Protestant) to get a chance to achieve his goals. Hitler found his idol in Richard Wagner. In his beliefs, Jesus Christ was Aryan, but was affected and influenced by the Jews and therefore his teachings were distorted.

Hitler's target was actually to destroy Christianity to make way for his German religion, but considering the percentage of German Christians, this was not possible, so Hitler started with the Jewish population.

Nonetheless there have been assaults on Catholic churches and priests too.

According to Hesemann, the destruction of Christianity in the Third Reich would have been Hitler's plan after the "Endsieg".

So, personally, I can't say if that is the truth, but it seems reasonable in some factors, but I want to close with a quote from Hitler, spoken in 1941:

> Christianity is a rebellion against natural law, a protest against
> nature. Taken to its logical extreme, Christianity would mean the
> systematic cultivation of the human failure.

Source:

*Michael Hesemann - [Hitlers Religion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12711476-hitlers-religion)*

Comment: I think that Hesemann is overinterpreting things. Sure, Hitler's approach towards religion was ambivalent. But I don't think that it was the result of some larger plan. While there was Nazi ideology and also attempts to make Christianity fit in (like proving that Jesus was Aryan), I would need solid proof to believe that Hitler was planning to replace Christianity by his own religion.

Comment: Without a discussion of what Hitler meaned with the term Christianity the quote is useless. What's the German original? What's the context?

Comment: Going against the Jews is purely against Christian beliefs. In a sense Natzism is a religion and Hitlers book Mein Kampf is the guidebook to that religion.

Comment: @Dorothy Going against the Jews was a strong Christian sentiment for centuries. It was even part of the Catholic lithurgy until the second half of the XXth century.

Comment: That last quotation sounds as though it could have come directly from Nietzsche.

Comment: A nice example of a Christian desperately trying to sweep his street clean.

Comment: @WS2 - That is indeed a paraphrase of Nietzsche's ideas, especially in its posthumous writings.

Comment: @cipricus If "Christianity represents the cutivation of the human failure" it seems to me surprising that it has lasted this long.

Comment: @WS2 - That is not my interpretation, but Nietzsche's, and it is the idea that Christianity continues Judaism as a sort of revolution made in favor of victims (which Hitler calls "failures") against immemorial traditions that value persecution, violence and sacrifice (sacrificing *others* that is!). "Failure" here means people that ideally reject violence. Nietzsche was not so naive as just to say (like Voltaire etc) that Christianity is a religion like any other, just hypocrisy etc. He didn't hate it for hypocrisy, but for trying to devalue violence (the glorious Greek and Roman values).

Comment: @WS2 - For an explanation of Nietzsche's position against Christianity, a pro-Christian position of great interest (because basically not religious, but anthropological,  like Nietzsche's but of opposite sign) is that of [Rene Girard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/René_Girard), who basically accepts Nietzsche's description but not the interpretation. In a way, Nietzsche and Hitler wanted the revival of pagan religion. Girard says that is madness and that they both prove this (one politically-one biographically). But G. greatly values N.'s depth and sincerity. Note that N. wasn't an antisemite!

Comment: @Jos - That is a rather naive reaction to what's at stake here. What Hitler, following Nietzsche, was trying to achieve was a religious revolution against what he saw as a decadence of the true values for which he blamed the Jews. Nietzsche mostly blamed the Christian *values*, not the failure to put those in practice. He explicitly defines all pacifist, humanist, socialist, egalitarian and democratic values as rooted in Christian ones, and rejects them all (or he tries to: his ides being infinitely more subtle than Hitler's).

Comment: @WS2 -Nietzsche says that we cannot really reject violence, but that, when we are its victims, or because we fear it, we just pretend we give it up: we don't like the fight because we are losers. Girard says: if all it's just illusion, how come N. is so furious against it as if illusion can have real impact? But things are more complex than this: G. agrees that it is in fact not possible for us to really be free of violence, but says that we just have the choice between trying and mutual destruction. Hitler chose the second.

Comment: @WS2 - `If "Christianity represents the cultivation of the human failure" it seems to me surprising that it has lasted this long.` Indeed. Hitler was not the only one to have a biased understanding of Darwinism. He thought that the stronger *must* survive, while Darwin says that who survives *is* the strongest. Nietzsche understood but rejected Darwinism: he thought that people *should* be trained, educated, self-domesticated according to Greek rather than Biblical models. Hitler tried to mix Darwinism with Nietzscheanism (and failed), and to replace philosophy with propaganda (and succeeded).

Comment: @cipricus I wonder if Nietzche may have changed his mind had he lived long enough to see a thermo-nuclear age.

Comment: @WS2 - Nietzsche was not a man of opinion, but profoundly and seriously  lived ideas and their contradictions to the core (maybe that has something to do with the fact that his nerves failed him), but I'm sure he was capable of outstanding new insights, had he lived more (maybe more fully against what was to become Hitlerism, as he hated German nationalism). Or maybe he was just lucky not to have lived to see future catastrophes.

Comment: @cipricus One thing that Hitler was not was a scholar. He borrows from all over the place, Nietsche, Darwin, etc. But he did not have enough formal education to assemble any compelling ideas of a religious or philosophical nature. He was an ignorant bigot, with the midset of a thug, but blessed with some political cunning, and oratorical skill, fed on a diet of anti-semitism, and nazi ideology - a creature born of the  moment in German history. There is a serious danger of over-thinking Hitler. At any other time he would never have been anything other than an ill-tempered corporal.

Comment: @WS2 - The problem is the "historical German moment" cannot be understood without Hitler! He is a more significant figure on many levels than a "scholar". In opposition to a philosopher like Nietzsche, Hitler must be defined as an *ideologue* - hence the bigotry - and of the anti-intellectualist kind at that. Nazi ideology, like it or not, is his invention, its history makes no sense without him, it was born out of his babbling, actions and discourse. Within that ideology, although less of an intellectual, he takes the same central position as Lenin does withing communism.

Comment: If you are saying that Hitler and Naziism existed within a symbiotic relationship, I certainly don't disagree.  But Fuhrer Hitler, is a character distinct from Corporal Hitler. The analogy to draw is not, in my view with Lenin but probably Lennon! The Beatle of that name which emerged at the head of a worldwide musical genre, was a distant stranger to the Skouse art student and lead guitarist. He had by 1968 created something that wasn't him, and which was a stranger to him. His biograhy by Albert Goldman is titled "The Lives of John Lennon" - there was more than one running in parallel.

Comment: There is probably room for a biography on the lives (plural) of Hitler the one contained within his own mind and body, and the other one that the world understood to be him - if you see my meaning.  But just to belabour the point about symbiosis between Hitler and naziism further - there is one regard in which I would disagree. At a university lecture I attended, the speaker began by saying "Germany, by 1933, would have had a Hitler - even if the young corporal of that name had been killed in the first world war". And there is no doubt in my own mind about that.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a Wiki page on it: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler's_religious_views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler%27s_religious_views)

**Below is a paragraph from the article above:**

> #### Persecution of the Christian Churches
>
> In 1999 attorney Julie Seltzer 
>   Mandel, while researching documents for the "Nuremberg Project",
>   discovered 150 bound volumes collected by Gen. William Donovan as part
>   of his work on documenting Nazi war crimes. Donovan was a senior
>   member of the U.S. prosecution team and had compiled large amounts of
>   evidence that the Nazis persecuted Christian Churches. In a
>   108-page outline titled "The Nazi Master Plan" Office of Strategic
>   Services investigators argued that the Nazi regime had a plan to
>   minimize the influence of the Christian churches through a campaign of
>   systematic persecutions. "Important leaders of the National
>   Socialist party would have liked to meet this situation [of church
>   influence] by complete extirpation of Christianity and the
>   substitution of a purely racial religion," said the report. According
>   to Annex 4 of The Nazi Master Plan, the best evidence came from "the
>   systematic nature of the persecution itself." The document further
>   stated that "direct evidence" of this plan could possibly be obtained
>   by examining the "directives of the Reich Propaganda Ministry" or by
>   "questioning of Nazi newspapermen and local and regional
>   propagandists". According to the outline, the Nazis understood,
>   even before they came to power, that they needed to neutralize the
>   Christian churches. The report stated, "the destruction of
>   Christianity was explicitly recognized as a purpose of the National
>   Socialist movement" from the start but "considerations of expediency
>   made it impossible, however, for the National Socialist movement to
>   adopt this radical anti-Christian policy officially." Historian
>   Alan Bullock agrees that it was Hitler's intention to wait until the
>   war was over to destroy the influence of Christianity. The O.S.S.
>   outline suggests that the plan to persecute the Churches was conceived
>   by Hitler and an inner circle before the Nazis even came to power,
>   however editor Richard Bonney stated this conjecture was an
>   "interesting, but undocumented, assertion." Some moves were made
>   to reduce Christianity's presence in German traditions, such as
>   replacing Christian elements in Christmas carols with pagan
>   references. In the political relations dealing with religion
>   Hitler readily adopted a strategy "that suited his immediate political
>   purposes".

Also in the wiki article:

> In 1985 the Austrian author Wilfried Daim published a photograph of an
>   alleged document signed by Hitler in 1943, which proposed the:
>
> "Immediate and unconditional abolition of all religions after the
>   final victory ('Endsieg') not only for the territory of Greater
>   Germany but also for all released, occupied and annexed countries ...,
>   proclaiming at the same time Hitler as the new messiah.

The reason there is ambiguity is because Hitler made himself appear like he supported Christian beliefs and at the same time he was moving farther away from them. If he immediately opposed Christianity he likely would never have risen to the power that he did so quickly.

If you know Christian beliefs you know that Hitler did not have Christian beliefs, no matter what he said. Actions speak louder then words.

In a sense Nazism is a religion and Hitler's book Mein Kampf is the guidebook to that religion.

**Two good resources to finding out his beliefs are:**

- Mein Kampf by Hitler himself
- The Bible (King James Version is good)

If you read them I'm sure you will find that his beliefs are nowhere near Christianity.

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you started.

Comment: If you know Christine beliefs you know that Hitler did not have Christine beliefs, no matter what he said. Actions speak loader then words. -- Hmm.... The muslims also make the same claim about the terrorists. Not saying that I disagree, but this is very very very open to interpretation.

Comment: And you think genocide is not justified by the bible?

Comment: Basically it's pretty good. However, is Hitler the only leaders that try to manipulate religions like this? Isn't all do? Another topic of the question.

Comment: The Wikipedia article has changed quite a bit since this answer was posted. That's one reason relying on it can be problematic.

Comment: "Christian" is a loaded and ambigous term. It is quite common to find (now-a-days and through history) 2 groups of people, both will call themselves christian and denouce the other as not christian,

Comment: Hitler was originally opposed by the Vatican, but that pope died and another came to power which approved of him. Did his actions change in relation to that? I wouldn't be surprised if he persecuted Catholics while the pope opposed him and stopped once the Vatican gave him their seal of approval.

Comment: Rather a good answer, but I am a bit baffled by the two reading suggestions at the end. While Mein Kampf should put some light on Hitler's beliefs (in the mid-twenties), I am pretty sure he is not mentionned in the Bible (but if you identify him with the AnteChrist or whomever might be mentionned in a doomsday prediction).

Comment: Evargalo, The question referenced Hitler's alleged belief in the Christian God. In order to better determine whether this is the case you would need to have both an understanding of Hitlers beliefs and an understanding of the Christian teachings. If a person claims "I am a Christian" and "I am a Nazi". You would need to understand both ideologies to see if they are able to reconcile and to see if the individual's actions are consistent with their claims.

Comment: The King James version? Really? Hitler didn't speak a word of English!

Comment: Hitler would likely have read Luther's translation, or a translation highly influenced by Luther's work. However, my assumption is most of the readers here do not speak a word of German, thus King James is suggested as a well established English translation for reference.

Comment: I don't see how the Bible (King James or any other) is relevant here. There are countless examples of Christians, from single individuals to state actors, performing atrocities of the worst kind imaginable. The "right" interpretation of scripture can serve as an excuse for much, and sometimes they just did it anyway, excuse or not.

Comment: Yes, Jesus warned of people who claim to be his followers but are not (see Matthew 7:15-23). The bible is a collection of source documents of the teachings of Christ and histories related. It is relevant to go back to the source.

Answer (score 9):

This is a very hard question to answer, and it's a hard question to even define!

You would have to decide what is a religious belief and what isn't (where do religion and politics overlap?). Hitler was big on racial supremecy (obviosly). Is that a religion? etc. Can one person have 2 (or more) religions?

You also have to decide what religions are called what. "Christian" is such a broad ambiguous term. It's common for there to be 2 religions, that would call themselves "Christian" and denouce the other as not Christian. Hence one person could say "Of course Hitler was Christian" and someone else can say "Of course Hitler wasn't Christian!". In order to answer this question, you would have to answer other questions like: Are Roman Catholics "Christian"? Are Anglicans "Christian"? Are Eastern Orthodox "Christian"?

This debate is futher muddy by combining the (well deserved) hatred of Hitler and what he did, and what Nazism stands for, with religion. Atheist Lobby Groups will say "Religion is bad, look Hitler was Christian" and Christian Lobby Groups will say "Atheism is bad, look Hitler was atheist!". If someone has a strong belief (either pro- one religion or anti a religion), they do not want to associate their grouping with Hitler. So many people will not approach this rationally and empirically, and will look for evidence to support the outcome they want to be true.

Comment: You make some good points.

Comment: Then there is a point that non trinitarian and the nude baptism practitioners are not "true" christians. By that definition one could argue that no terrorists are true muslims.

Answer (score 7):

What were his religious beliefs? The reason this is worth answering is because it helps to answer a truly important question: what was the role of religion in Nazi Germany? After all Hitler is only interesting or important because he was the leader of a powerful country.

Historically, answers to this question have been contaminated by the No True Scotsman fallacy so common in discussions about religion. Christianity is good, and Hitler was not good, so Hitler wasn't a Christian. Even though Hitler said he was a Christian, this is not true because he was a Nazi, and therefore not good, and therefore not a Christian (there's good reason to think Hitler's profession of Christianity was insincere, but we'll get to that later). You can see the same pattern of thinking among Marxist-Leninists: Bolshevism is good, Stalin was not good, therefore Stalin was not a Bolshevik. And Islam is good, and ISIS is not good, therefore ISIS is not Islamic. And so on.

Buddhism is good, and the Buddhist mobs attacking Muslims in Sri Lanka are not good, therefore they are not Buddhists. Hinduism is good, and the Gujarat pogroms by Hindus were not good, therefore the perpetrators were not Hindus. And so forth.

I will confine my answer to Hitler's actions and self-identification, rather than saying whether he was a 'true Christian', because per Wittgenstein, universal terms like Christian can only have family resemblances and not a single defining characteristic. Of course (some) Christians believe there is a single internally coherent and true version of Christianity (theirs), and all other interpretations are heresy. However I am not a Christian, so thankfully I don't have to pretend that there is one true interpretation, so I won't.

The other leg to understanding his beliefs is Hitler's actions. How did he behave towards Christians and other religious groups, and what were his future plans?

Now we've got that out the way, as I said we'll take a direct look at Hitler. First there's his public statements. They are pretty unambiguous: Christianity is good, atheism is bad. He said some rude things about Catholicism, but anti-atheism was the main thrust of his arguments. [This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_views_of_Adolf_Hitler) cites quite a few of them; it was part of his attempt to discredit his Social Democrat and Communist rivals. All this worked, and he got the support of German Christians: the vast majority of those in his party were practising Christians. We know this for the simple reason that 95% of Germans were Christians.[2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_Nazi_Germany) Even if every single non-Christian had been a Nazi member (many were Sozis or Commies, wherefore Hitler's anti-atheist propaganda) then mathematically they would still be swamped by Nazi-supporting Christians going by 1939 population figures. Note that per the above paragraph I am not making some essentialist claim that theoretical 'true Christians' supported Hitler, I'm saying that practical Christians, who lived, breathed, and physically existed supported him.

Many atheists were executed; not necessarily communists, just anyone who had vocally supported some party other than the Nazis. A small minority of Catholics and an even smaller minority of Protestants interpreted their religion as incompatible with the Nazis' rule, and were also executed. These people are very famous (and boasted about) so I won't go into detail, except to say there is nothing contradictory in persecuting Christians *and* atheists. Remember, the first Christians were executed by the Romans *for being* atheists, in that they denied the existence of the Roman gods. And as we'll see below, Hitler had his own gods.

Hitler's private statements were less friendly to Christianity. He viewed it as a religion of weakness, and planned to extinguish it after the war was over. However, it is not accurate to characterise him as a secret atheist. He believed in some kind of divine presence, which was guiding the German race to master the world.

That's how he saw himself, anyway. In practical terms he never had a solid grip on reality, and after a couple of successful annexations he went totally off the rails; he believed that he was God. Both his statements and actions back that up. Unlike many of his Nazi colleagues, he really had no interest in neo-paganism and did nothing to encourage it.

I said above that Hitler's religious beliefs are not as important as people think they were. Hitler is not the same thing as Nazi Germany. If Hitler was not a Christian, this does not mean that Christianity came out of the war with clean hands. People make a big fuss out of Bonhoffer and Niemoller these days, but the uncomfortable fact is that most Germans, and therefore most Lutherans and a good chunk of Catholics, supported Hitler partly because he portrayed his war as a war against Bolshevist atheism, and inflamed their long-standing antisemitism.

To the extent that these people were complicit in the crimes of the Nazi state, they did not see a contradiction between their crimes and their Christian identity and beliefs. This may mean they were 'not true Christians', but what use is the concept of 'true Christians' if most people who think they are Christians are just confused? Equally, what use is the idea of 'true Communism' if none of the Communist regimes in history have been 'true Communists'?

Comment: I think this answer is remarkable, but I think that if we take history and religion (and religious ideas, and history of religions) a bit more seriously, we could say that Hitler and Nazi Germany are a significant phenomenon in that sense. To really be in a position where Christianity was seen as expendable, but also replaceable with some sort of pagan-national one (like the French revolution also tried at one point!) needs more explaining than saying Christians are still to blame. `what use is the concept of 'true Christians'` - of no use whatsoever.

Comment: The distinction is that the revolutionaries openly declared their hostility towards Christianity. Hitler hid it from view, and convinced Christians to participate in his ill deeds. Casting himself as the defender of Christianity against Bolshevism was a successful tactic.

Answer (score 6):

Because of his importance to history, and his oft-described sense of messianism at the time of his early successes, I think some people often look to Hitler to provide evidence of a comprehensive philosophy, which would include things like his religious views.

But I am not sure that knowing what he thought about any religious or philosophical subject is of any more value than knowing what anyone of a substantially maladjusted psyche thinks on the matter. Hitler was both a megalomaniac and a fantasist. I am certainly not prepared to attach any value whatever to knowing the religious views of such a troubled individual. For all practical purposes Hitler was the personification of evil. Attempting to divine from his writing or speeches some kind of devout motive, behind his warped ideas, seems to me entirely ridiculous.

We do know that he had been brought up, at least nominally, as an Austrian Catholic. But Hitler's expressed religious beliefs in *Mein Kampf* and elsewhere do not follow any consistent pattern. He would bore the staff at his HQ with lengthy dinner monologues about the history of mankind, the nature of the cosmos, interwoven with narcissistic stories about his youth in Vienna, and his "struugles".(Kershaw). He would repeat endlessly his justifications for anti-Semitism, which as Alan Bullock points out borrowed heavily from attitudes of some red-necked Austrians of the early-twentieth century, and especially the visceral prejudices of the gut-right-wing elements of some of the German-speaking *petit bourgeoisie* in cosmopolitan Vienna. This corresponds with the time Hitler was a down-at-heel artist, mixing with ne'er-do-wells in down-market cafés and doss houses. Almost certainly he did not have the capacity and mindset to develop and sustain a consistent religious position, radically outside of the mainstream. As far as I know, he was not a man given to spiritual reflection.

During the days of his youth, when he was trying to make it as an artist, Hitler pretended to intellectual thought - but based on Bullock's assessment it was shallow. The milieu in which he lived during this period of his life i.e. the time when many young people give thought to life's big questions,   was hardly conducive to the sort of profound thought and discussion necessary for developing religious and philosophical positions.

It is also worth remembering that Hitler, though he did not lack for political cunning, was not an academically educated man. (Before he became a politician he had been a corporal in the army.) There is ample evidence that he was ill-at-ease in educated company. He was far more comfortable in a beer hall - especially if he was able to grab the floor, and, heaven-forbid, a microphone.

Hitler's religious utterances throughout his life tend to be disorganised and haphazard, perhaps not unlike the expressions of someone not tied into a church structure, and lacking the disciplines of higher education. Nor do they indicate any particular personal religious commitment.

There were times when the Nazi regime was embarrassed by the criticism of religious people, such as when sections of the public became aware of the extent of the euthanasia programme. Kershaw* ,reporting on Hitler's attitude around the end of 1941, says "there would be no place in this utopia [an "eastern Reich covering most of Russia] for the Christian churches". And Goebbels in his diaries commented at the time 'There is...an insoluble opposition between the Christian and a Germanic-heroic world-view'. Later Kershaw (p516) records Hitler as having indicated his determination, (Spring 1942) "after their insidious behaviour during the winter...to destroy the Christian Churches after the war". And when he was persuaded that the Vatican was deeply inplicated in the plot to oust Mussolini, in a military briefing, Kershaw says that he talked wildly of occupying the Vatican and "getting out the whole lot of swine". (Kershaw p596)

The religious question had bedevilled German unification for centuries, and one of Hitler's predecessors, Otto von Bismarck, (Chancellor 1871-1890) had pursued a *Kulturkampf* against Catholics, in which the term *Reichsfeind* (Enemy of the state) had been widely employed. The notion of a cultural "enemy within" was not therefore new to recent German history. Thus it was that politicians who wanted to succeed as badly as Hitler, needed to tread carefully as between Protestants and Catholics in a Federal Germany.

It would appear from reading historians such as Kershaw* that there was religious pressure - notably from Catholics - on the regime from time to time, but the Nazi authorities were careful, it would seem to keep it under control and it was not allowed to develop into a contest.

Events may to some extent have followed a pattern set in the later 19th century, where religion in Germany, as elsewhere in Europe, had undoubtedly been challenged by intellectuals. The writings of German philosophers such as Marx, Hegel, Nietzsche, as well as scholars elsewhere, such as Charles Darwin, feed into the general *zeitgeist* of the defeated post-war nation, and undoubtedly influenced the climate in which National Socialism prospered. Hitler's *pot pourri* of ideas and expressions borrow variously from these different sources.

Who knows what Hitler would have become had he ultimately been successful, and what path he might have taken as regards the churches? He would not have been the first German Chancellor to have taken on the Roman Catholic Church if that had been his plan. **So in answer to the question, I believe that while Hitler, like many in society, would have had a perfunctory religion of Catholicism, any *beliefs* associated with his divers utterances on the subject, from time to time, were held more in service of his political ambitions than for personal reasons. Hitler's only really compelling ideologies were national socialism and German world domination**

**There exists on YouTube an [excellent lecture on Christianity in Nazi Germany by UK historian Professor Alec Ryrie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEdnwpo28NM) which is well worth the 55 minutes that it lasts.

*Ian Kershaw; *Hitler 1936-1945; Nemesis* (London 2001).
*Alan Bullock; *Hitler: a Study in Tyranny* (London 1962).

Answer (score 4):

Adolf Hitler was a self confessed positive Christian

**Positive Christian**

[Religious views of Adolf Hitler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_views_of_Adolf_Hitler)

> Hitler and the Nazi party promoted "Positive Christianity",[11] a movement which rejected most traditional Christian doctrines such as the divinity of Jesus, as well as Jewish elements such as the Old Testament.[12][13] In one widely quoted remark, he described Jesus as an "Aryan fighter" who struggled against "the power and pretensions of the corrupt Pharisees"[14] and Jewish materialism.[15]

Adolf Hitler was also in to mysticism and occultism.
Whilst some historians say his interest was fleeting, that did not stop him promoting Occultists to the highest positions in the Nazi party.

**Hitler on mysticism and occultism**

[Mysticism and Occultism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_views_of_Adolf_Hitler#Hitler_on_mysticism_and_occultism)

> According to Bullock, as an adolescent in Vienna, Hitler read widely, including books on Occultism, Hypnotism, Astrology. However, his interest in these subjects was fleeting, and there is no evidence that he ever subscribed to any of these schools of thought.[99] Bullock found "no evidence to support the once popular belief that Hitler resorted to astrology" and wrote that Hitler ridiculed those like Himmler in his own party who wanted to re-establish pagan mythology, and Hess who believed in Astrology.

Though Hitler was in to Occultism as a youth.

> According to Ron Rosenbaum, some scholars believe the young Hitler was strongly influenced, particularly in his racial views, by an abundance of occult works on the mystical superiority of the Germans

And while Hitler publically condemned Occultists in his society, he still promoted them to highest realms of Nazi party

> Although Hitler expressed negative views towards the mystical notions of some of his senior Nazi underlings in private, he nevertheless appointed Heinrich Himmler and Alfred Rosenberg to senior positions in the Nazi movement.[50][51]

Comment: But it is fundamentally a *pot pourri* of nonsense. He may have "read widely" in Vienna - but his readings were like a lot of those of the uneducated which go unchallenged. If I read a lot of books for example with titles like "God was an Astronaut" that present absolutely incontrovertible accounts of UFOs, conspiracy theories etc - and I never get challenged by a tutor or a professor about the ideas I'm developing - that does not make me a well-read person. From Bullock's account the young Hitler seems to fit that stereotype of an undisciplined and gullible reader.

Answer (score 2):

Hitler was not Atheist, Protestant or Catholic. Perhaps in Hitler's early life he may have considered himself a catholic or protestant or even sincerely doubted there was a God and declared to himself an atheist. It is obvious that he was never really a practicing Christian of any denomination and that as far as religion goes he considered Church organizations as political organizations, to be replaced by the Nazi system of belief, just as all other political organizations at the time in Germany.

This answer is informal and just my opinion based on a lot of reading over the years about Hitler and the war.

Hitler was not an atheist, because Hitler believed in his own divinity. Hitler believed that he was chosen by divine providence to save the German race. Hitler's God was to Hitler the only true God. Hitler believed that everything he did was morally correct. He believed that any thought he had was of divine origin. As far as Hitler was concerned, Hitler was infallible because he was the true servant of God. No matter how many people died, no matter how much destruction was wrought at the bequest of Hitler, to Hitler it was all moral because it was of his divine will. In his megalomania he could not distinguish between his will and the will of god, for him it was one in the same. As far as religion was concerned, he was above it, he was the only true representative of god. Nazism was the only true religion, because Hitler was the only person in the world that was perfectly divine and understood God and  God's will.   The only moment of doubt that Hitler *may* have had about this is when he was biting the cyanide and pulling the trigger.

Comment: Lots of opinions, very few citations. Difficult to engage with this on a scholarly level. Your opinions are valid, but opinions don't advance historical scholarship.

Comment: I will work on it a bit, in the next week or so, I had some citation in mine, but half my books or in the attic.

Comment: Hitler certainly believed in *Schicksal* (fate, or destiny) as responsible for his having been born on the border of Austria and Germany (*Mein Kampf* ch 1.). And its fulfiment in his mind would be in his becoming the agency through which the two great German nations would become one. But I was not aware that his vanity extended  so far as to consider himself personally divine. Where did that idea come from?

Answer (score 1):

Adolf Hitler was a believer not in traditional Abrahamic faith, but a form of monotheism. According to Historian Percy Ernst Schramm, a [German historian who infiltrated the Nazi's inner circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percy_Ernst_Schramm), Hitler's religion is "a variant of the monism so common before the First World War". [Monism is the belief that only one supreme being exists](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/monism). Historian Maximilian Bernhard Domarus says Hitler believed in a [personal "German" god](https://books.google.com/books?id=0Y0UULmcFt0C&pg=PA21). Hitler even stated:

> "I believe in God, and I am convinced that He will not desert 67 million Germans who have worked so hard to regain their rightful position in the world."

Basically, Hitler wasn't an atheist or Christian like many claim, but he was a monotheist who believed in his own God that would leave the German people to victory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Wikipedia page which attempts to answer this exact question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_views_of_Adolf_Hitler).

The upshot of the analysis is that Hitler was originally Catholic, but stopped attending mass at age 15.

The [official position of the Nazi party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_Nazi_Germany) (and therefore of its Fuhrer) was constructive Christianity, meaning that all Christian religions were tolerated. In practice, the party persecuted church leaders if they criticized the regime at all. So, while toleration was the official policy, any sort of divisive behavior in the name of religion was heavily punished.

Personally, Hitler exhibited the behavior of an [agnostic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnosticism), never attending church services, and never expressing any belief either in public or in private as to the existence of a power higher than man. Towards those who had faith, he was antagonistic and suspicious; often expressing the view in private that religious faith was contradictory to party progress. This behavior was consistent with and typical of socialist/communist leaders and thinkers of the time.

Comment: Stalin tried to wipe the churches out, Hitler successfully brought them onside. As for social democrats elsewhere, many of them were practising Christians, some were atheists, none of them tried to wipe out religion. Those things are not consistent with each other.

Answer (score -1):

A form of Social Darwinism.

Hitler's view were actually very similar to  Madison Grant and Lothrop Stoddard. The idea that there was one unique aristocratic race that carried "the burden of civilization."

From here he assumes that there's a "natural order" in life devised by Nature. So he replaces God with Nature and religious laws with natural laws that are immutable. Eugenics and blood are actually very similar as well. Since you can interchange the concept of "IQ" with "vitality of blood."

"All the great civilizations of the past became decadent because the originally creative race died out, as a result of contamination of the blood. The most profound cause of such a decline is to be found in the fact that the people ignored the principle that all culture depends on men, and not the reverse. In other words, in order to preserve a certain culture, the type of manhood that creates such a culture must be preserved. But such a preservation goes hand-in-hand with the inexorable law that it is the strongest and the best who must triumph and that they have the right to endure. "-Mein Kampf

Sources: 
"The Revolt Against Civilization," Lothrop Stoddard.
"Mein Kampf," Hitler.
"Hitler's second book," Hitler.
"Landmark Speeches of National Socialism," Randall L. Bytwerk.
"The Passing of the Great Race," Madison Grant

Comment: Thanks, I will in add more in the future.

Answer (score -1):

> What were Hitler's religious beliefs?

Not much is known (based on **facts** and **knowlage**) that can be varified.

Based on my reading about **he whom I do not desire to cite (other than how *not* to act as a responsible person)**, the following seems to me to be the most realistic:

> [Adolf Hitler - Ideologie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler#Ideologie)
> Hitler blieb trotz Ablehnung der Amtskirchen, die er als Konkurrenz auf ideologischer und organisatorischer Ebene sich unterzuordnen suchte, zeitlebens Mitglied der römisch-katholischen Kirche.
>
> > Hitler remained a lifelong member of the Roman Catholic Church, despite the rejection of the official churches, which he tried to subordinate to himself as competition on an ideological and organizational level.

Other than that, **he whom I do not desire to name** is **not** the only person, in the course of history (or even in the present day (-written on Easter Sunday (slightly sloshed)-)), who has not acted in accourdance to the lessons (possibly) taught as a child.

One answer on this question quotes, as a source that in the provided link, states that the author:

> became known in Germany as an author of several books on UFOs and extraterrestrial visitors on Earth. Later in his career he turned to topics related to Catholicism.

- is this to be considered a reliable source? [Really?]

The other (presently of the 14 answers (all togeather)) offer some (possibly) philosophical posibities as to what **he whom I do not desire to name** (*he*) actually believed in.

For me, (again slightly sloshed while writing on this on Easter Sunday) it is important to point out, that not withstanding, what *he* (possibly) was taught to believe, that *he* did not practice it

- so what is the point in asking what belief *he* belonged to that *he* didn't practice?

Important is, in my opinion, only that *he* (and **not** the pitiful imitations of the present day) to be considered the prime example of **what not to follow**

- thankfully for everyone else they ('The beloved leader' or the 'stable genius' of the day) are too stupid to recognise this

So the answer to the question 'What were Hitler's religious beliefs' has, in my personal opinion, based on his activities as a politician (between 1920-1945), nothing to do with established religions.

So, as an historian, I believe that *he* did not practice what most religions preached as being **good**.

(And thus the Easter Sunday preach comes to an end, which (as always) the greater portion of congregation gives a (discrict) great sigh of relief.)

---

**Sources**:

- [Adolf Hitler - Ideologie – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler#Ideologie) (in German)

Answer (score -6):

Hitler was atheist, church was only an instrument for him. 62% of the Germans were Protestants and 32% were Catholics, so it was important to work together with the church, which might seem to be impossible, because Christianity is based on altruism and national socialism definetely not. But as always Hitler had some good working propaganda stuff going on...

For the Protestants there was a the "Glaubensbewegung Deutsche Christen"(religious movement of German christians)[Protestants] initiated by the NSDAP to get more influence on the church. Most protestants voted for them, because they promise to reunite the churches to one (there have been28 regional churches). But the Nazis also had some strong enemies in the Protestantic church: the confessing church

The Catholics didn't accept the Nazis first, not till Hitler promised to let them keep their intitutional rights. Then they started working together officially, but many critics have been chased.

[Text by the German Historical Museum(only German)](http://www.dhm.de/lemo/html/nazi/innenpolitik/kirchen/)

[Kirchenkampf- Hitlers attitude toward the churches in Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchenkampf)

Comment: Naziism always claimed an altruistic aim. Just going by what they actually said, they promoted 'mental hygeine' and eugenics which were seen even outside of Nazi Germany as the key to a better life for everyone. Even the US carried out eugenics programs. George Orwell wrote a review of Mein Kampf in which he talks about the fact that Hitler asked people for self sacrifice for the greater good, and that this was more successful than telling people a better life would simply be given to them.

Comment: he gives references and I do not think this a bad answer to a tricky question.Upvoted.

Comment: I see nothing in that answer that supports the strong claim in the three first words. Actually the (undated, unreferenced) statistics with 62% Protestants and 32% Catholics most probably included baptised people, like Hitler, in the 32% of Catholics.

Answer (score -7):

Hitler was most likely an atheist who respected the cultural values of German paganism. Nazi propaganda was notably anti-religious and the "Nazi Master Plan" involved the eradication of religion from Nazi Germany.

Many senior Nazis were also devout  anti-theists like Joseph goebbels, the Nazi Minister of Propaganda.

If Hitler wasn't an atheist, he most certainly was anti-religious at the very least judging by his desire to remove religion from Germany.

The better question then is why do atheists continue to deny his anti-religious beliefs and promote lies that he was a Christian? In Hitler's Table Talk, he's quoted as calling Christianity a lie, worst than the pox and invention of the Jew. That alone should tell you he didn't like Christianity.

Comment: Please read a bit more *about* ["Table Talks" and their reliabilities](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/52941/26786). But the rest could do with references as well. Please add sources.